# Window does not grow to accommodate when I replace a placeholder NSView with a big view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have small windows with a button on it and a small placeholder cusom NSView, when the button is clicked I reaplce the the custom view with another created out of a xib file.

The new view shows up fine but it is cropped because of the smaller window size. How can I make the window to grow wide only as much so that my new view fits in..

// This code is written inside a controller _connectWindow is pointer to my window where there is a button and _custom place holder.  _progView is the NSView that I am loading from the xib file

```
    -(IBAction)connect:(id)sender
     {
     if(!_progView)
     {
       [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"ConnectionStatusView" owner:self];               
     }           

     [[_connectionWindow contentView] replaceSubview:_custom with:_progView];
```

I would appreciate a more specfic response, I have read this article http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html but it did not help much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `replaceSubview:with:` here. It looks like you should just be using [`addSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCCCEII). You can resize the window by setting its frame: [`setFrame:display:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCICJEFA) or `setFrame:display:animate:`.

Comment: Thanks, but probably the key question is getting NSRect because setFrame needs a rec and I do not have it, if I calculate it from the newview, it won't be suitable because my window has another control too .. Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to calculate it. I don't see why that should be a problem. You know the current size of the window, the frame of the added view, and you can easily get the frames of any other views in the window.